# Is it still possible to post to a fan page as the page using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have code which:

- Asks for manage_pages and publish_actions permissions for the user
- Gets a long-lived access token for the user.
- Gets /me/accounts to list the pages for which this user is a Page Admin
- Gets the access token for a page, say with ID PAGE_ID (which I can verify using the debugger has a Profile ID of the page in question and an expiry of Never, and the manage_pages and publish_actions permissions)
- (A few minutes later) Tries to POST to /PAGE_ID/feed using that access token

I am getting "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

Most discussion of this predates the retirement of the offline_access permission.  Posting to the user's feed works, but posting to the page feed doesn't.  I'm wondering whether my code is bad, or whether Facebook have removed the ability to post to fan pages (as opposed to users) in this way using the Graph API.

Is anyone successfully still doing it?

Comment: Of course it’s still possible. You are simply dealing with an expired access token here. So get a non-expiring one: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: I've verified the token using the debugger, and it shows a profile ID of the page in question and an expiry of never.  Sorry, I should have said that - I've edited the question to clarify.

Do you have code which is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which language you are using though it shouldn't matter, as long as you are pulling the page token you should be fine.

You can verify this by going into the explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and

- getting the page token `/me/accounts`
- setting to `POST` and calling `/PAGE_ID/feed` with a field `message`

If you cannot get past the second step, try a GET request to  `/me` with the page token, you should be getting the page and not the user.

Comment: I'm using PHP, but I see the same behaviour using the explorer tool as well.  

Have you successfully done this recently?

Comment: If I do a GET to /me then I do get the page, btw.